# Accessing application running inside pod in browser

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I want to access an application running inside pod from the browser.

Yaml file of pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app-pod6
  labels:
    name: app-pod
    app: containerization
spec:
  containers:
  - name: appimage1
    image: appimage6:1.0
    ports:
     - containerPort: 3000
```

When I do

```
curl localhost:3000/app/home
```

its giving me response inside container. Now I want to access it from browser.

I created a service for exposing application using command:

```
kubectl expose pod app-pod6 --name=app-svc6 --port=3000 --type=NodePort
```

And when I do describe service, it gives me Nodeport: 31974
And when I do 'ip add', I get kubernetes ip as 192.168.102.128
But cant access application from 192.168.102.128:31974

Comment: It looks like the pod is running a `sleep` command, and not a webserver, right?

Comment: @Jonas...I have removed it. And added CMD ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null"]
in Dockerfile to keep container running.

Comment: How would that work? I suggest that you run a webserver listening on port 3000 instead.

Comment: @Jonas...when I bash into container, I start the application using startapplication script. And curl localhost:3000/app/home is giving me response. That means app is up inside container on port 3000

Comment: Why don't start the application in the command? then you don't need the `sleep` command.

Comment: Which IP address are you using? Is that the IP of the node or the Pod?

Comment: @AndD Its ip address of node

Comment: @Jonas....ive started the app inside pod. And removed sleep. Its not getting exposed still

Comment: Just a thought. Can you make sure the application is not binding on 127.0.0.1? It should be binding to 0.0.0.0 to make itself available to clients outside the container.

Comment: @JulioHM... I have a properties file. In which it is server is already configured to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Can you show the output of `kubectl get svc -owide -n <namespace>`?